# What would be regular expression to split following string in php?

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

**string**

```
T1 - X1(1), 7
T2 - C2(-9), -15
T3 - Y2(1), 3
T5 - C2(-1), 100
```

**regexp used for preg_split**

```
$pattern = "/[-,#\n#()]/";
preg_split($pattern, $string);
```

> In above regular expression it is considering the hyphen space same as minus in front of a number.

**Final Result Required**

array having after preg_split and trim space `["T1","X1","1","7","T2","C2","-9","-15","T3","Y2","1","3","T5","C2","-1","100"]`

What changes can I make in the regexp pattern to achieve the final result required?

Comment: Try [`preg_match_all('~-\d*\.?\d+|[^-\s,#()]+~u', $s, $matches)`](https://regex101.com/r/O95ziL/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should skip the negative numbers. This can be done with PCRE verbs:

```
-\d(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\s*[-,#\n#()]\s*
```

PHP example:

```
$string = 'T1 - X1(1), 7
T2 - C2(-9), -15
T3 - Y2(1), 3
T5 - C2(-1), 100';
print_r(preg_split('/-\d(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\s*[-,#\n#()]\s*/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

1. https://3v4l.org/m51qS
2. https://regex101.com/r/659ocz/1/

Answer (score 0):

You could match either a whitespace character, a hyphen and a whitespace `s-\s` character or `|` match the characters you want to exclude `[(),\s]` using a character class:

[`\s-\s|[(),\s]`](https://regex101.com/r/KCiTsz/1)

```
$data = <<<DATA
T1 - X1(1), 7
T2 - C2(-9), -15
T3 - Y2(1), 3
T5 - C2(-1), 100
DATA;

$result = preg_split("~\s-\s|[(),\s]~", $data, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

print_r($result);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/l7FM4U)